# Convert array and other variables together into a JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a array and 2 variables like this

```
var data = ['12','23', '45'];
var location = 'school'
var details = 'student';
```

I want to convert this to a json as follows

```
{
"School Details":[
     {"data":"12", "location":"school", "details":"student"}, 
     {"data":"23", "location":"school", "details":"student"},
     {"data":"45", "location":"school", "details":"student"}
]
}
```

Please note: the value of data array is dynamic and can vary. However, the variable 'location' and 'details' will remain the same all the time. I need to constantly insert this static value to the dynamic array values in a json.

Does anyone have a idea how I could achieve this? This is a bit complicated scenario.

Comment: step 1 - create a javascript object. Step 2, `JSON.stringify` this object to get your required JSON string

Comment: note: don't use GLOBAL var name location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use array#map to map the each value in data to the object required

Use JSON.stringify to convert the resulting object to a JSON string as required

```
var data = ['12','23', '45'];
var loc = 'school'
var details = 'student';
var object = { "School Details": data.map(function(item) {
        return { data: item, location:loc, details:details };
    })
};
var json = JSON.stringify(object);
console.log(json);
```

> NOTE changed `var location` to `var loc` because using `var location` in global scope was messing things around in the browser